# AMPScript Lookup() with multiple values

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible if I can print multiple values from Lookup(). So for example I want to print the following values in an email;

Address 1
City
State

Here is my code but seems it is not working.

```ampscript
%%=Lookup("Policy","Address 1","City","State","PolicyNumber",PolicyNumber)=%%
```

Is there a way to have a one lookup done and we can print multiple values from DE.

I tried creating multiple lookup values and it works, but it does not seems to me an effiecent way. For example the following method work.

```ampscript
%%=Lookup("Policy","Address 1","PolicyNumber",PolicyNumber)=%%
%%=Lookup("Policy","City","PolicyNumber",PolicyNumber)=%%
%%=Lookup("Policy","State","PolicyNumber",PolicyNumber)=%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Timothy mentioned, you will need to utilize a block of AMPscript for this.

What you need to do is create a rowset via [LookupOrderedRows()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) or [LookupRows()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) functions.

After this you would use [Row()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm) to select which row and then [Field()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm) to select the specific field you want.

See below sample:

```
%%[
SET @PolicyNumber = AttributeValue("PolicyNumber")

SET @Rows = LookupRows("Policy", "PolicyNumber", @PolicyNumber)

SET @Row = ROW(@Rows, 1)

SET @Address = Field(@Row, "Address")
SET @City = Field(@Row, "City")
SET @State = Field(@Row, "State")
]%%
Address: %%=v(@Address)=%% <br />
City: %%=v(@City)=%%<br />
State: %%=v(@State)=%%<br />
```

Comment: It's great... I just have to fix one thing that is

SET @Row = ROW(@Rows, 1)

Answer (score 5):

You're going to need a larger AMPscript code block to do it.  Have a look at user Adam Spriggs blog at https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/